# php array ranker based on value

Tags: php, arrays, ranking

I am searching how to build a array ranker based on a value.

I have an array output like:

```
key => 0 | id => 16103 | Thumbs => 0 
key => 1 | id => 23019 | Thumbs => 0 
key => 2 | id => 49797 | Thumbs => 5 <- key 2 needs to switch with key 1 
key => 3 | id => 51297 | Thumbs => 0 
key => 4 | id => 58106 | Thumbs => 0 
key => 5 | id => 59927 | Thumbs => 4 <- will be stay at this position 
key => 6 | id => 61182 | Thumbs => 0
key => 7 | id => 68592 | Thumbs => 0 
key => 8 | id => 70238 | Thumbs => 10 <- key 8 needs to switch with key 6 
key => 9 | id => 71815 | Thumbs => 0 
key => 10 | id => 78588 | Thumbs => 0 
etc..
```

I would like to write a function to reproduce the array output above as follow.
When a record has 5 thumbs it needs to move 'one' higher in the output, when it has 10 thumbs 2 higher and so on.

I guess I should reproduce the array at first to set the key (prio) for each output like 100,200,300 so we have enough space to set a row between?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want key 8 at top, key 2 at second position and then every other entry with 4 or less? or does key 2 just go up to key 1 and key 8 to key 6?

Comment: I think you should make some counter (one more field) in which you store temporary "thumbs" and if it reaches five, you sort array by this and then set it to zero, so it won't go up twice.

Comment: @Chris these results are coming from a search action so they have already a certain weight. I won't throw all that away to say result with most thumbs is the best. I want to make a kind of combination between the search algorithm and user_inputs that's why I would like to rank 'gently' by the (by user input) given thumbs. 5 thumbs means one position higher, 10 thumbs 2 positions higher etc.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in your example you'd better use an array of arrays. (If you aren't already, it's not clear from the question.) Like so.

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = array('id'=>16103, 'Thumbs'=>0);
$array[1] = array('id'=>16103, 'Thumbs'=>0);
...
```

Then, start by writing a swap function.

```
function swap (&$arr,$key1,$key2) {
    $temp=$arr[$key1];
    $arr[$key1]=$arr[$key2];
    $arr[$key2]=$temp;
    // the & before the $arr parameter makes sure the array is passed as a reference. So no need to return the new array at the end.
}
```

Now for your ranking function:

```
function rank(&$arr) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        if ($arr[$i] < 5) continue;
        $places_to_move = $arr[i]['Thumbs'] / 5; // get number of places to promote the entry
        $places_to_move = max($places_to_move, $i); // make sure we don't move it out of the array bounds
        swap($arr, $i, $i - $places_to_move);
    }
}
```

Then simply call your rank function for your unranked array

```
rank($array);
```

Comment: Why downvote? I think this is better approach than my answer.

Comment: It won't give me ranked results back, getting the array through the function delivers same array :/ Your function seems to rank the results ok?!

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you have an array of arrays:

```
$array = array(
    array('key' => 0, 'id' => 16103, 'Thumbs' => 0), 
    array('key' => 1, 'id' => 23019, 'Thumbs' => 0), 
    array('key' => 2, 'id' => 49797, 'Thumbs' => 5), //<- key 2 needs to switch with key 1 
    array('key' => 3, 'id' => 51297, 'Thumbs' => 0), 
    array('key' => 4, 'id' => 58106, 'Thumbs' => 0), 
    array('key' => 5, 'id' => 59927, 'Thumbs' => 4), //<- will be stay at this position 
    array('key' => 6, 'id' => 61182, 'Thumbs' => 0),
    array('key' => 7, 'id' => 68592, 'Thumbs' => 0), 
    array('key' => 8, 'id' => 70238, 'Thumbs' => 10), //<- key 8 needs to switch with key 6 
    array('key' => 9, 'id' => 71815, 'Thumbs' => 0), 
    array('key' => 10, 'id' => 78588, 'Thumbs' => 0) 
);
```

In this case, you can use `usort()`:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    $a_thumbs_val = floor($a['Thumbs']/5);
    $a_val = $a_thumbs_val ? $a['key'] - $a_thumbs_val - 0.5 : $a['key'];

    $b_thumbs_val = floor($b['Thumbs']/5);
    $b_val = $b_thumbs_val ? $b['key'] - $b_thumbs_val - 0.5 : $b['key'];
    return ($a_val > $b_val) ? 1 : -1;
});


var_dump($array);
```

would produce:

```
array (size=11)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'key' => int 0
      'id' => int 16103
      'Thumbs' => int 0
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'key' => int 2
      'id' => int 49797
      'Thumbs' => int 5
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'key' => int 1
      'id' => int 23019
      'Thumbs' => int 0
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'key' => int 3
      'id' => int 51297
      'Thumbs' => int 0
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'key' => int 4
      'id' => int 58106
      'Thumbs' => int 0
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'key' => int 5
      'id' => int 59927
      'Thumbs' => int 4
  6 => 
    array (size=3)
      'key' => int 8
      'id' => int 70238
      'Thumbs' => int 10
  7 => 
    array (size=3)
      'key' => int 6
      'id' => int 61182
      'Thumbs' => int 0
  8 => 
    array (size=3)
      'key' => int 7
      'id' => int 68592
      'Thumbs' => int 0
  9 => 
    array (size=3)
      'key' => int 9
      'id' => int 71815
      'Thumbs' => int 0
  10 => 
    array (size=3)
      'key' => int 10
      'id' => int 78588
      'Thumbs' => int 0
```

Note: 2 entries that should be on same position might be either way arround, since usort does unstable sort. You can go arroud that by enhancing that closure in usort, adding some more complicated comparing.